# вопрос о срезах в python (на тему включения первого числа)

Tags: python

как использовать срез в python без включения первого числа ?

```
n = int(input())
n_num = int(input())
a_list = []
while n > 0:
    a_list.append(n)
    n -= 1

a_list.reverse()

b_list = []

while len(a_list) > 1:
    print(a_list)
    b_list = [*a_list[n_num:n_num]]
    del a_list[::n_num]

print(*b_list)
```

Часть кода, которую я пишу, должна убрать из списка все 3 числа несколько раз, пока в списке не останется одно число, но мои попытки тщетны, прошу вас помочь именно с помощью СРЕЗОВ, а не циклов.

Comment: `del a_list[1::n_num]`

Comment: *a_list[n_num:n_num] - что, по вашему мнению, это должно делать?

Comment: @EzikBro разве не начало в n_num и шагом в n_num?

Comment: @Danis тогда код просто удаляет первое 3 число , а остальные не трогает

Comment: можно пример входных и выходных данных?

Comment: @Danis ввод:10 и 3 вывод: 4

Comment: @ДамирНабиуллин 
`a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`
`n_num = 2`
`b_list = [*a_list[n_num:n_num]]`
`>>b_list`
`[]`

Comment: Шаг в срезах определяется третьим параметром. Вы же задали только границы, причем таким образом, что в них не входит ни один элемент

Comment: @EzikBro а как тогда будет правильно ?

Comment: `b_list = a_list[n_num::num]`

Comment: Смотря что вам нужно. Я рекомендую вам просто прочитать синтаксис срезов и конкретные примеры использования, как например `a[::-1]`, `a[:]` , `a[1:-2:3]`

Comment: @Danis вывод тот самый , вы ведь только поправили распаковку списка и допустили ошибку так как переменой num  нет